# PHP7: shouldn't a scalar return type declaration accept integer?

Tags: php, return-type, scalar

I'm implementing an Iterator interface and if I implement it returning scalar (following the reference http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php), I got this error:

> TypeError: Return value of Collection::key() must be an instance of
>   scalar, integer returned

The class implementation:

```
class Collection implements \Iterator
{
    public function key(): \scalar
    {
        return key($this->colecao);
    }
    // other methods implementations...
}
```

According to the PHP reference, integer should be considered a scalar value (http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php):

> Scalar type declarations come in two flavours: coercive (default) and
>   strict. The following types for parameters can now be enforced (either
>   coercively or strictly): strings (string), integers (int),
>   floating-point numbers (float), and booleans (bool).

Is there some mistake in my code your would it be a bug?

Thank you for any explanation!

Comment: `public function key(): int` is what you need. You have to specify which scalar type it returns.

Comment: Return types can only be http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.types No such thing as scalar that I have heard of

Comment: The types shown in PHP documentation are not real types that you can use in code, they're just meant to be descriptive to human readers. E.g. there's no type named `mixed`, it just means that the function can return multiple types.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, thank for the help. I had put the return type with int, but I had no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP does not have a type known as `\scalar`. PHP only supports [those](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.php) types. And your `\scalar` type looks like it is another class.